# Finding the width of TileList - scrollbar width Flex

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, actionscript

I've got a TileList with verticalScrollPolicy="on".

Is there a property that returns the width of the tileList minus the width of the scrollbar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know of any property but in flex builder 3 you can open a class by going to the menu navigate>open type and type scrollbar in the box at the top. This will allow you to open the scrollbar.as file ans see that the first declared constant is THICKNESS which is set to 16. THICKNESS is described in the comments as

```
/**
*  The width of a vertical scrollbar, or the height of a horizontal
*  scrollbar, in pixels.
*/
```

So the the width you want can be calculated by:

calcWidth = myTileList.width - 16;

Comment: Yea cool. Apparently, that's a static property, so I'm accessing it as Scrollbar.THICKNESS